# How to overcome Xcode 4 errors when learning Objective C by Kochan book

Tags: objective-c

So, I'm learning Objective C by this book.
It is thought to be great and all.
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303332025&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

But after installing new Xcode (version 4) when i tried to finish the exercise form the book (3.2) it gives me like 10 compilation errors that I can't identify.
What can I do about this?
Getting xcode 3 is not really an option.
For example there are many semantic errors that keep saying undeclared identifiers pointing to empty spaces...

also it isn't accepting this line of code:

```
Fraction *myFraction;
```

I got class myFraction, what's wrong with this one?

Also there is method declaration in this class

```
- (void) setNum : (int) n;
```

it says, expecting member name or  ; after declaration specifiers.
What can this mean? There already is a semicolon there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Fraction *myFraction;`
>
> I got class myFraction, what's wrong
>   with this one?

In this statement, `Fraction` is the name of your class... `myFraction` is the name of your object.  If your class is really called myFraction, this statement would be:

```
myFraction *myFraction;
```

> Also there is method declaration in
>   this class
>
> ```
> - (void) setNum : (int) n;
> ```
>
> it says, expecting member name or ;
>   after declaration specifiers. What can
>   this mean? There already is a
>   semicolon there.

I don't see anything wrong with this... can you post the code that surrounds this method declaration?

Comment: This helped. but I'm still getting over 9000 useless errors. Also, what does line myFraction *myFraction mean? I can't understand.